# How to delete user from Auth0 on Next.js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, next.js, auth0

I can login and logout users on Next.js after reading these resources amongst others:

- [The Ultimate Guide to Next.js Authentication with Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/ultimate-guide-nextjs-authentication-auth0/)
- [@auth0/nextjs-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0) library
- [API Call Example](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/tree/master/examples/api-call-example)
- [SPA + API: Node.js Implementation for the API](https://auth0.com/docs/architecture-scenarios/spa-api/api-implementation-nodejs)

But nowhere could I find out if I can delete users using the auth0/nextjs-auth0 library.

I also looked into the module's handlers [here](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/tree/master/src/handlers).

Am I right to think there is no way to delete a user using the @auth0/nextjs-auth0 library?

If yes, what is the most preferred way to delete a user? I'd like to allow users to click a button in the browser to delete themselves from Auth0.

At this point, I'm thinking of using [node-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/node-auth0) library to do it following this [solution](https://community.auth0.com/t/how-do-i-delete-a-user-from-auth0/6618):

```
 management.users.delete({ id: USER_ID }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      // Handle error.
    }
 
    // User deleted.
  });
```

But it requires a node back end, which I sort of wanted to avoid. Even so, is this the best solution or are there better ones? The Auth0 ecosystem is quite sprawling.

*Edit 27 Oct 2020*: Will try using node-auth0 library in "serverless" function in Next.js to allow user to delete their account over the weekend. Secrets are hidden with Next's [runtime configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration). If this is not the best way to do it, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I'm following Nextjs' docs on its [runtime configuration](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration) to hide secrets

Comment: You want to hide secrets, so you must implement a backend (small enough), it could be a separate project or use the Next.js API route (allow you to build the backend in the server side of Next.js).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean logging out a user by "deleting a user". Because If you want to delete a user from the database, you have to have node server which handles the db connection. If you want to log out the user, in "pages/api/v1" create a logout.js. in next.js, serverless functions or api functions are written in "pages/api".

```
import auth0 from "/utils/auth0"; 
// auth0 file is where you set the configuration for the auth0.

export default async function logout(req,res) {
  try {
    await auth0.handleLogout(req, res);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.status || 400).end(error.message);
  }
}
```